# Counting number of times that the name already choose or voted

Tags: vb6

I'm trying to make a voting system in visual basic 6.0 using Combo Box and Command Button.

The thing I would like to happen is when the user choose the name in the combobox and click the command button which renamed as "Submit" the number of votes will be counted and print into the Label.

So far, i only had this.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Combo1.AddItem "Jeff"
    Combo1.AddItem "Gerwen"    
End Sub
```

Comment: now is this vb.net or vb6? - Anyway: what label? Is there one label for each answer? Or do you want to change the text in the combobox? - You should first think of a good data-structure to use here (a map/dictionary comes to mind) - don't try to just "change" UI texts counting numbers pls

Comment: You mean until this year?

Comment: metacomment: I really don't understand the downvotes and even close comment here - you don't like the lang. I get it - but that is NOT a reason to downvote

Comment: Beyond the odd choice of language, I don't understand the question, which is a reason to close/downvote.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it should be like this:

```
Public jeff_counter as Integer
Public gerwen_counter as Integer

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Combo1.AddItem "Jeff"
    Combo1.AddItem "Gerwen"
    jeff_counter = 0
    gerwen_counter = 0
End Sub

Private Sub Command3_Click()
    if Combo1.text == "Jeff" then
       jeff_counter = jeff_counter + 1
    else
       gerwen_counter = gerwen_counter + 1
    end if

    Label1.text = jeff_counter
    Label2.text = gerwen_counter
End Sub
```

You can improve it, by using array of integer, It's been a long time since I used VB6, so maybe there is a typo..

Comment: Thank you, it worked!!!  yeah there is a typo but i already fixed it! anyway thanks.